# Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы Jackson пропускал поля с нулевыми значениями в JSON?

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, сериализация

Окей, возможно описал не очень корректно в названии, легче будет описать так:

Вместо этого, при сериализации:

```
{
  "field": null
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы было:

```
{

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11757487/6766879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы свойства со значением null не сериализовались, вы можете или настроить [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html), или использовать аннотацию [`@JsonInclude`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html).

---

Игнорирование null-значений на уровне класса - в JSON не будут записываться поля равные null:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Foo { 
  public String field;

  Foo(String field) {
    this.field = field;
  }
}
```

Игнорирование null-значений на уровне поля - только *это* поле не запишется, если у него будет null:

```
public class MyDto {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String stringValue;

    private int intValue;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

---

Вы также можете настроить `ObjectMapper`, чтобы только при использовании конкретного маппера свойства с null значением не записывались в JSON:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

---

[Источник 1.](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields)
[Источник 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449211/how-to-prevent-null-values-inside-a-map-and-null-fields-inside-a-bean-from-getti/11464975#11464975)

Comment: а для чего нужно, зачем игнорировать null значения?

Comment: @Санаев я не знаю. Но если автор задал вопрос и  есть для этого даже есть специальные механизмы - значит для чего то нужно

Comment: @Санаев, REST-API который я использую требует этого.

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ если он решает ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если работаешь в Intelij Idea, то плагин Extra Java Inspections в помощь!